# I am having trouble in building code using espressif idf for esp32. Can anyone help me?

Tags: windows, esp32, toolchain

I want to code my esp32 using espressif idf. I am new to espressif idf.

I installed the offline esp idf in my laptop from   https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.3-beta1/esp32s2/get-started/windows-setup.html#get-started-windows-tools-installer.

Next I referred to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byVPAfodTyY to start my work, but while building the code, I got one failed message:

> FAILED: esp-idf/mbedtls/x509_crt_bundle
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> ninja failed with exit code 1

[my screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr8d4.png)

Can anyone help me? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The Espressif certificate bundle includes one which is considered to be faulty by the latest version of the cryptography pip package. If you google the error message, you'll immediately arrive at the Espressif bug report which [describes the issue and offers a workaround](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/5322#issuecomment-962219803)

Quoting from that:

> You can do it with idf.py menuconfig as follows:
> Navigate to Component config --> mbedTLS --> Certificate Bundle --> Default certificate bundle options and choose use only most common certificates, then build again. Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much for your answer... let me try and share the feedback

Comment: I CANT find this component config ----> mbedTLS ---> certificate bundle ---> default certificate bundle options. anywhere. so i skipped my try using esp IDF and tried through ESP IDF eclipse. there i can successfully build my code.

Comment: There's a menu-based configuration tool which is launched using idf.py (that's the main thing you use in ESP IDF command line). You launch the ESP IDF CMD or Powershell, naviate to your project root, execute the command `idf.py menuconfig` and that's it.

Comment: after navigating to my project root, i ran install.bat and export.bat. then i ran idf.py meuconfig. it opened.  then as tarmo told, i did the procedure. navigated to component config--> mbedTLS-->certificate Bundle --> Default certificate bundle options --> use only  most common certificates. it successfully built and uploaded. but when i try my own code from workspace, i get again this ninja failed error. the reason it says is, "A fatal error occured: this chip is esp32 not esp32-s2. wrong --chip argument? --chip esp32s2 failed.

Comment: The error message says you've chosen the wrong chip version as your build target. What else do you need to know to fix it?

Comment: I dont know the reason for this bug. everything i faced when i ran the code from espressif IDE. now i uninstalled everything and installed esp idf tool. now i am able to build and upload the code using eclipse ide. thank you.